# Multiple tags with same name in xsl

Tags: xml, xslt

The below is my xml file structure

```
<pgblk>
<task revdate='somedate'>
</task>
<task revdate='somedate'>
</task>
<task revdate='somedate'>
</task>
</pgblk>
```

I have many tags with same name (task tag) and am trying to get the greatest revdate here. My XSLT is as follows:

```
    <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="updatedrevdate" select="'19000101'" />
        <xsl:for-each select="pgblk">        
            <xsl:for-each select="task">
                <xsl:when test="@revdate &gt; updatedrevdate">
                    <xsl:variable name="updatedrevdate" select="revdate" />
               ------i want to update the variable updatedrevdate to be revdate but it is not possible since reassigning a varaible is not possible in xslt-------
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

Any possible help? Much appreciate the help in advance.
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming all your "dates" are in the format YYYYMMDD (and so can be treated as numbers), what you need to do is simply sort the `task` elements (using `xsl:sort`) in descending `revdate` order, and pick the first one

Try this template

```
<xsl:template match="/pgblk">
    <xsl:for-each select="task">
        <xsl:sort select="@revdate" data-type="number" order="descending" />
        <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
            <xsl:copy-of select="." />
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Note I am matching `pgblk` in the template, rather than doing an `xsl:for-each` because in your sample the `pgblk` is the root element, so will only be one of them.

EDIT: If you want to store the result in a variable, just wrap the `xsl:for-each` in an `xsl:variable`.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="text" />

    <xsl:template match="/pgblk">
        <xsl:variable name="updatedrevdate">
            <xsl:for-each select="task">
                <xsl:sort select="@revdate" data-type="number" order="descending" />
                <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
                    <xsl:value-of select="@revdate" />
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:value-of select="$updatedrevdate" />
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

See it in action at http://xsltransform.net/bEzjRKy

Comment: Thanks Tim :) btw, this doesnt work. I'm unaware of what might have gone wrong with the above code. the final revdate has to be stored in a variable as it needs to be used in a different block.

Comment: I've expanded my answer to show how you store the result in a variable. See it in action at http://xsltransform.net/bEzjRKy. Note, it might help if you amended your question to show more realistic values in the `revdate` attributes, rather than just "somedate". Thanks!

Comment: Hi Tim,first: thank you so much for your help :) the code worked when the XML was smaller, but when applying the same to a larger XML it is failing. Can you please tell what might be the issue here ? I tried it in below link 
  http://xsltransform.net/jxDigUE/4

Comment: I took a look at that link, and see an error "Error reported by XML parser: The system identifier must begin with either a single or double quote character." which is due to the DOCTYPE statement not being the correct format. Even if you remove the DOCTYPE line, the XML itself is not well-formed. For example, the `<colspec>` tags are not closed. You would need to correct all these errors first before the XSLT can be applied.

Comment: Hi Tim. We have a DTD where we have defined the process for <colspec> and the <colspec> doesnt need any close tags. The xml is converting to html without any errors in the system. Is there any way to avoid the considering of the close tags ? Also the file is SGML and not xml.. sorry for the confusion...Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think XSLT works on SGML in general. Only well-formed XML (which is a subset of SGML). You might need to ask a new question here, making sure you tag it appropriately, and mention you are working with SGML. (I don't know much about SGML, only XML).